# Mapping between JSTOR stable ids and DOIs for Publications of the Royal Society of London

Tags: data-request, doi, data-mapping

Is there a mapping between the [DOIs](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/faq#question6) used by the Royal Society of London and the  [Stable URLs provided by JSTOR](http://jstor.org)? I am looking specially for the publications of the Royal Society of London (Philosophical Transactions, Abstracts, Proceedings) before 1923.

EDIT: Some sample jstor_id's: 102661, 106670, 109020, 111263, 110829, 112791

Answer (score 1):

Will this help:

[Get a DOI id given a Jstor Id](http://try.unigraph.rocks/?q=%7B%0A++subjects(property%3A+%22jstor_article_id%22%2C+identifier%3A+%2289013%22)+%7B%0A++++uid%0A++++jstor_article_id%0A++++doi_id%0A++++title.en%0A++++publication_date%0A++%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Refer to the Unigraph documentation [here](https://github.com/unigraph/docs/wiki) to build your queries.

Use the keys: DEMO or WebDemos or request your own from api @ ingen.io

Comment: I tried some jstor_id's in the range of interest for me, and at least the demo returned nothing (but it explicitly states that it does not reveal the full data).

Comment: It is also very possible that the jstor_id to doi that you have been interested in, given and the time period (before 1923) might as well not have been correlated. Meaning that there's a jstor_id but no doi id or vice versa for a particular entity(ies).

Comment: I know for sure that there are both jstor_id's and DOIs (registered retroactively by the Royal Society of London itself) for the articles in question. I will edit the question giving some sample jstor_id's.

Comment: Does the RSL provides a data dump of their data which reflects this?

Comment: I am not aware of available data dumps. The DOIs are published (e.g.)  on the pages below this page http://rstl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/by/year (e.g., http://rstl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/54.toc ). The HTML is quite well-structured and possible suitable for knowledge extraction. Unfortunately, the jstor_id's are not contained in these pages.